# Is there always a connection such that $\nabla_i\mathbf e_j=0$ for some basis $\{\mathbf e_i\}_i$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, connections

Consider a smooth manifold $M$, with a local basis $\{\mathbf e_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Can a connection $\nabla$ such that $\nabla_i\mathbf e_j=0$ for all $i,j$ always be defined?

For context, the question comes from watching some lecture videos on youtube (*e.g.* [this one](https://youtu.be/mXitbCtbmBg)) explaining tensor calculus notation. In there, the speaker defines the covariant derivative in such a way that $\nabla_i\mathbf e_j=0$ for all $i,j$, so that we have
$$\partial_i \mathbf V
= (\partial_i V^k + \Gamma^k_{~ij}V^j)\mathbf e_k
\equiv (\nabla_i V^k)\mathbf e_k,
\qquad \mathbf V\equiv V^j\mathbf e_j,$$
defining $\nabla_i V^k\equiv \partial_i V^k + \Gamma^k_{~ij}V^j$.
I *think* the expression $\nabla_i V^k$ can be understood as simply shorthand for $\mathbf e^k(\nabla_i\mathbf V)$ (as otherwise, what would it mean for a covariant derivative to act on *functions* rather than vector/tensor fields?), but I am not confident about this.

All this is introduced, in the linked videos, in the context of *flat surfaces embedded in $\mathbb R^n$*. What I am looking for here is the more abstract justification for these types of formal manipulations. In particular, in the video they end up with a covariant derivative such that $\nabla_i\mathbf e_j=0$, which should imply vanishing Christoffel symbols (for $\nabla$ wrt the basis $\mathbf e_i$). But then again, they get Christoffel symbols in the expression for $\partial_i\mathbf V$, so my interpretation is that they are really dealing with *two* different covariant derivatives: the trivial one in the embedding space, which corresponds to the standard directional derivative, and has Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ used above, and this other $\nabla$, which is something different.

Which naturally spurs the question: can we always define such a covariant derivative which gives zero with respect to a given basis? If not, under what conditions can it be done?

Comment: perhaps you mean $\nabla _i=\nabla _{\mathrm e_i}$? If this is the case, as $\nabla _{\mathrm e_i}\mathrm e_j=: \Gamma ^k_{i,j}\mathrm e_k$ then you can choose the Christoffel symbols such that $\nabla _{\mathrm e_i}\mathrm e_j=0$ for every $i,j$, by example setting $\Gamma ^k_{i,j}:=0$ for every $i,j,k$

Comment: @Masacroso yes, that's what I mean. I suppose my question is whether that can be done in general. I've simply never seen it states, and the only times I've encountered vanishing Christoffel symbols were for flat Euclidean spaces in canonical coordinates, or for things like normal coordinates (but then $\Gamma=0$ only at a point). Moreover, with such a choice, we'd get $\nabla_i\mathbf V = (\partial_i V^j)\mathbf e_j$, which would make the coordinate system "look Euclidean". I wasn't sure whether this is possible in general.

Comment: @gsl for every choosing of $n^3$ functions $\Gamma ^k_{i,j}$ you have a connection. You can choose these functions at will (but they need to be smooth). Note that Im talking about (affine) connections in general, not some special connection as the Levi-Civita connection, what is already determined by the metric

Comment: just another thing: by definition of connection if $f$ is a smooth function and $X$ if a vector field, then $\nabla _Xf:=Xf$

Comment: If you mean identically $0$ rather than $0$ just at a point, then there is a parallel frame field if and only if the curvature vanishes.